# Open firefox with subprocess.Popen in python

Tags: python, firefox, subprocess

I try to start a firefox subprocess with `subprocess.Popen` on my mac:

`p_firefox = Popen(["firefox", URL_SITE, URL_SCRIPT], stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)`

But I keep getting the following error:

`Error opening firefox, it may not be installed [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'firefox'`

**Tries:**
When I run `which firefox` on my terminal it's not available either.

This lead me to putting the firefox bin on my path, which I did by updating `.bash_profile` with `export PATH="/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin:$PATH"`

I now see it on my path, but still get the same error, still `bash: firefox: command not found` on the terminal and still the same error when running `Popen`

I also find lot's of selenium related solutions, but those are not relevant in my case.

**Question:**
How can I open firefox with `subprocess.Popen` in python?
`p_firefox = Popen(["firefox", URL_SITE, URL_SCRIPT], stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)`

Comment: The name of the executable is `firefox-bin` and the directory you should add to the `PATH` is `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS`

Comment: If the binary is not on your PATH, you can always specify it explicitly.
`p_firefox = Popen(["/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox", URL_SITE, URL_SCRIPT], stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)`